# ( ((batterycharging= 0)/duration))

Tags: mysql

Can anyone explain me What this expression does? Thanks in advance

If I ran the following query in MYSQL

select batterycharging, duration, ((batterycharging= 0)/duration)  from 
battery_info;

The results are the following:

[image]

Comment: that looks like a bad syntax, where did you get the equation from?

Comment: @Martin: what's wrong with the syntax? It looks like bad style indeed, but the syntax is ok.

Comment: Hi Martin, I got it from my workplace.  Someone wrote the query this way and I have to program it in ETL tool.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: I said it *looks like* bad syntax, mainly due to the number of brackets, I don't know if it actually is, but is curious, at least.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns `1 / duration` if  `batterycharging` is zero, `0` if a non-null number other than zero, `NULL` if null.